# Mysql installation on aws ec2 instance through userdata

Tags: mysql, bash, amazon-web-services, automation, user-data

I am giving this script as a userdata in an ec2 instance to install and setup mysql. The code runs fine manually but when given to ec2 instance as userdata it doesnot creates the database or user.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y install aspell aspell-en httpd24 mysql mysql-server php56 php56-cli php56-gd php56-intl php56-mbstring php56-mysqlnd php56-opcache php56-pdo php56-soap php56-xml php56-xmlrpc php56-pspell --skip-broken
sudo yum list installed
sudo /sbin/chkconfig httpd on
sudo /sbin/chkconfig mysqld on  
sudo /sbin/service httpd start
sudo /sbin/service mysqld start
sudo mysqladmin -u root password '123a'
sudo mysql -u root -p123a
CREATE DATABASE db;
CREATE USER '1234'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '123a';
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO '1234'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**Mysql version: 5.7.28**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grant command is not right, nowadays it is simply without password

```
sudo mysql -u root -p123a -e  "CREATE DATABASE db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;use db;create user 'db'@'localhost' identified by '123a';  grant all on testdb.* to 'db';GRANT ALL ON db.* TO ' db '@'localhost';GRANT ALL ON db.* TO ' db '@'%';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

Comment: You need an  -e  as option and the sql command in double quotes see changed answer

Comment: I have tried with -e but its not working. I have updated the code but the problem remains the same. Its like i am unable to enter the mysql console through ec2 instance user data. When I run the command manually it works.

Comment: you command doesn't use -e also you need a database as bas for your query. see changed answer, also don't use cariage return

Comment: I have added mysql version too if there is any query issues. I have tried many ways still unable to figure that out

Comment: not accourdimng to this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-accounts.html try the hole query in mysql workbench or so

Comment: Don't you find it strange that the query works perfect when ran manually but doesnot work when given as a user data?

Comment: it runs perfectly, what i find starge that you didn't get an error message